# JQuery binding click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[**JSFIddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/47w6os53/)

Problem:

`click` event is working for `button` *Click Me* but `click` event is not working for `label` *Click Me*.  Below is the code

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="clickMe" class="btn">Click Me</button>
<div class="preview">

</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
    var lab = "<label class=\"click\">Click Me </label>";
    $('.preview').append(lab);
});

$('.click').click(function() {
    alert("You clicked on text");
});
```

Comment: Read about [`Event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$('.preview').on('click', '.click', function() {
    alert("You clicked on text");
});
```

Comment: `$('.preview').on('click', '.click', function() {.....` would be better.

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla Yes you are right, if we are certain that `$('.preview')` is not dynamically. I thinks that is the case here.